# Find a preimage in $\Bbb Q[X]$ for $\left((X^2-1)\pmod{X^3-5},(X+2)\pmod{X^2+X+1}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[X]\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}[X]/\langle X^3-5\rangle\times\mathbb{Q}[X]/\langle X^2+X+1\rangle$. Is $\phi$ surjective?

Comment: By "overjective", do you mean "surjective"?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Check out [the abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619), and fix your post. I'm afraid it currently falls very short of the standards expected on this site.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much. I'll read it.

Comment: I would start by writing $x^3-5$ as $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)-4$ and go from there

Comment: The title is confusing because in the body of your question there is no anything about preimage. What preimage are you talking about? When we take preimage, we should specify set or some element.

Comment: @VasilyBolbachan The title was confusing because it had been distorded by someone else. I rolled back and tried to improve.